# Dell Inspiron 5420 wifi drivers PCI ID 14e4:4365

Tags: dell-inspiron, ubuntu-12.04, wifi-driver

I recently bought a new Dell inpiron. I need it for educational purposes and a wifi connection is really important.

Wifi is working properly in Windows7 but Ubuntu 12.04 is not even detecting the wifi card.

I even tried running via ndiswrapper but unfortunately that is also not working.

Any pointers in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to wailt a little bit more: [Bug #923809 “Upgrade bcmwl to verison 6.20.55.19 (r300276) or gr...”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/923809)

Comment: On Fedora 17 also didn't work, Update solution for me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same chipset in my Dell Inspiron 5520. I use Fedora 17. After lot of internet research I compiled the following howto.

First, install development tools like gcc (`yum install gcc`) if not already installed. Then download the file from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178352/broadcom-4365-wireless-driver-on-12-04-with-3-4-3-5-kernel) and do the following steps:

1. `sudo yum install dpkg`
2. `mkdir BCM43142`
3. `dpkg-deb -x Downloads/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb BCM43142`
4. `cd BCM43142/usr/src/wireless-bcm43142-oneiric-dkms-6.20.55.19~bdcom0602.0400.1000.0400/src/wl/sys`
5. `sudo yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers`
6. `vi wl_linux.c`
7. around line 46, remove the line `#include <asm/system.h>`
8. save the file (`:wq`)
9. `cd ../../..`
10. `make`
     Things should work, and you'll have a file called "wl.ko" in the current directory.
11. `sudo yum remove broadcom-wl`
12. `sudo mkdir -p /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra/wl`
13. `sudo cp wl.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra/wl`
14. `sudo depmod -a`
15. `sudo modprobe wl`

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=283824

This should work for Ubuntu as well, just change the package names where necessary.

Note: Wireless N is not supported in this driver version.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad and Indrek, will check and post back (and close this question hopefully :) )

Comment: It worked finally with little changes here and there : like using apt-get install instead of yum

Answer (score 0):

Re-install the drivers:

> sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
>
> sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Hope it helps.

Comment: This isn't working